# How to remove hostname, pid and other default fields from Bunyan log output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bunyan

These are default fields

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "hostname": "banana.local",
  "pid": 40161,
  "level": 30,
  "msg": "hi",
  "time": "2013-01-04T18:46:23.851Z",
  "v": 0
}
```

How can I remove `hostname`, `pid` from json output or use `bunyan` pretty output tool to hide those fields?

Answer (score 1):

[Per the author](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/issues/187#issuecomment-63019613), it isn't officially supported but you can delete them manually with this. See the post for potential pitfalls.

```js
delete logger.fields.hostname;
```